# How to create a static global event so that one form can listen to another form's event that isn't a parent form?

Tags: c#, events, static

I'm using WinForms and I have 3 forms. FormA, FormB, and FormC.

FormA creates FormB, FormB creates FormC.

I need FormA to know when FormC closes. FormB has no participation.
I also have a global static class that each Form have access to.

I've looked at [How to properly listen form events with another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994230/how-to-properly-listen-form-events-with-another-form) and [Propagating events from one Form to another Form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977326/propagating-events-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-c-sharp) but they only apply to FormB listening to FormC.

How can I create an event in the global static class so that FormA can listen to FormC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost always 100% better off avoiding `static` classes and global references.

It's better to pass down an `Action<FormC>` that allows you to notify back that `FormC` is closing.

Try this:

## `FormA`

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formB = new FormB(this.ClosingC);
        formB.Show();
    }

    private void ClosingC(FormC formC)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Closing C");
    }
}
```

## `FormB`

```
public partial class FormB : Form
{
    public FormB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Action<FormC> _closingFormC = null;

    public FormB(Action<FormC> closingFormC)
        : this()
    {
        _closingFormC = closingFormC;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formC = new FormC(_closingFormC);
        formC.Show();
    }
}
```

## `FormC`

```
public partial class FormC : Form
{
    public FormC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Action<FormC> _closingFormC = null;

    public FormC(Action<FormC> closingFormC)
        : this()
    {
        _closingFormC = closingFormC;
    }

    private void FormC_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _closingFormC?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is using static classes and global references a bad idea? I thought it is a good idea because FormB does not do anything else besides creating FormC, and user can create other instances of FormBs and not have it wait until FormC is done to close and alert FormA.

Comment: @csharpnewbie - Eventually you'll hit a situation where you want to have multiple instances of `FormA` open and you need to know which one started the chain of `A -> B -> C`. A static reference won't work then.

Comment: @csharpnewbie - Also you can't unit test static classes - it makes your code fragile.

Comment: @csharpnewbie - With my code you can augment the `Action<FormC>` to do logging or testing, etc. The code in `FormB` could write this for example: `var formC = new FormC(c => { MessageBox.Show("Calling A now from B When Closing C"); _closingFormC(c); });`. There are plenty of reasons why `static` classes are bad.

Comment: Events are preferable to Actions, because they allow multiple subscribers. It would be better for the FormB to expose an event FormC_Closed. Then FormA could subscribe to the event FormB.FormC_Closed, and FormB could subscribe to the event FormC.FormClosed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Actions are no different to events - you can have multiple subscribers. But that doesn't seem to be the problem here as calling an action like this can be done by multiple callers - no different from multiple subscribers to an event. I don't see the distinction that you're raising?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Also, the OP specifically says that `FormB` creates `FormC` but otherwise plays no part - we must assume that `B` could close yet we still want `A` to be notified with a `C` is closed. `B` has to be the one to pass on the callback method to `C` if we avoid static classes.

Comment: @Enigmativity suppose you had two instances of FormA, and both instances should listen to the closing of a single FormC, through a single FormB. Does your implementation support this scenario?
About the scenario of using events and the FormB closing before FormC, the only implication it has (I think) is that FormB would not be garbage collected before the closing of the FormC.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I have specifically written the code to allow separate `FormA` instances to know about their own `FormC` instances. The question implied that that was important.

Comment: My point is that by using events you would be able to support a greater range of scenarios, without writing additional code, and without departing from the event-based paradigm of Windows Forms development.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - What greater range of scenarios? It doesn't matter about events and actions - they are effectively the same thing. You can do the same with both. You're either passing around a delegate or passing a reference to an object with a delegate - it's still just a delegate.

Comment: Can you expose the Action<FormC> _closingFormC (inside FormB) so that multiple instances of FormA can subscribe to it? If you can't, then there you have a scenario that can be supported by events, but not by actions.

Comment: A small comment about [static classes and global references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151768/are-global-static-classes-and-methods-bad). Global mutable data are a liability. Global immutable data are OK. Static methods that don't modify global data are excellent.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, pure functions are good, but what you're suggesting in your answer is global, mutable data.

Comment: My answer provides what the OP asked. He asked specifically for an event in a global class. Such an architecture is debatable, since it could degrade the performance if overused, but I wouldn't call an event 'data'. The events are not data.

Answer (score 0):

I would use event aggregation.  Here is a small one `Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator`

used like

```
public class MyForm : Form, IHandle<MyEvent>
{
   public MyForm() 
   {
      SomeStaticPlace.EventAggregator.Subscribe(this); //Can be replaced with DI
   }

   public void Handle(MyEvent message) 
   {
      //Act on event
   }
}
```

And publish `SomeStaticPlace.EventAggregator.Publish(new MyEvent(...));`

Comment: Is this used in the FormC and published to the global static class and then the FormA subscribe to it?

Comment: MyForm above is the listener. You publish from anywhere to invoke it

Answer (score -1):

This is the global static class with the static event `FormClosed`:

```
public static class GlobalStaticClass
{
    public static event FormClosedEventHandler FormClosed;
    public static void OnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormClosed?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

This is `FormC`. Raises the `FormClosed` event:

```
public partial class FormC : Form
{
    public FormC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            GlobalStaticClass.OnFormClosed(sender, e);
        };
    }
}
```

And this is `FormA` that listens to this event:

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GlobalStaticClass.FormClosed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //if (sender is FormC)
            MessageBox.Show(((Form)sender).Name + " Closed, reason: " + e.CloseReason);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I have trouble here in the FormA part because FormA does not know of FormC and therefore cannot call FormC.instanceClosed.